# Linking new Field in existing Table to Form textbox in Access 2010

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access Database that I have been asked to make some modification to. These include adding a new field on a form and linking it to a new field in one of the link Tables.

I have an accdb file and a _be.accdb file I'm working with, with the accdb file being the front-end and the other file being the back-end database.

I have added the new field to the back-end database, and I can see it when I look at the tables in the front-end. But when i try to add the new field to the Control Source property of a new textbox I can't find it. I typed the name of the field in manually but when I test it I get an error '#Name?'...when I switch the control to another existing field that I can 'see' I do not get this error.

I've tried removing the linked table I'm looking at and then re-adding the link but still can't see the new table field.

Is there a trick I am missing to re-linking the new table fields in the back-end to the front-end?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the form is based on a query, not directly on the table. Then you might need to add the new field to the query (if the query doesn't `SELECT *`)

Comment: If you're still having trouble, please show us what you have as the form's Record Source property.

Comment: I will look into that, not sure honestly. I'm not used to working in Access, I do our stuff in sql server, which is why i was asked to work with this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know where I would look to tell if the form is Query driven?

Comment: Open the form in Design View and then open its property sheet.  Look at the Record Source property on the Data tab of that property sheet.

Comment: Thank you that got me rolling!